# Screen overflowing when keyboard appears over dialog in Flutter even after using singlechildscrollview

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, singlechildscrollview

Here's the code where I'm opening a dialog on click of FloatingActionButton:

```
FloatingActionButton(

                        elevation: 4,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Get.defaultDialog(
                            title: 'Add Reminder',
                            titleStyle: kSubHeading2TextStyle,
                            content: Container(



                              height: screenSize.height * 0.7,

                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                controller: ScrollController(),
                                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),


                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                      builder: (dropDownController) {
                                        return DropdownButton(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                          elevation: 12,
                                          isExpanded: true,
                                          underline: const Divider(
                                            thickness: 2,
                                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                                          ),
                                          hint: const Text(
                                            'Select Category',
                                            style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                          ),
                                          value: dropDownController.dropdownvalue,

// Down Arrow Icon
                                          icon:
                                              const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                                          items: dropDownController.categoryItems.map((String items) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                                              value: items,
                                              child: Text(
                                                items,
                                                style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                            dropDownController.changeCategory(newValue!);

                                          },
                                        );
                                      }
                                    ),
                                    const Text(
                                      'Journey Date & Time',
                                      style: kSubHeading2TextStyle,
                                    ),
                                    GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                      builder: (calendarController) {
                                        return SizedBox(
                                          height: 100,
                                          child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                            initialDateTime: calendarController.focusedDay ,
                                              onDateTimeChanged: (datetime) {
                                            print(datetime);
                                            eventDateTime = datetime;

                                          }),
                                        );
                                      }
                                    ),
                                    const Divider(
                                      thickness: 2,
                                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                                    ),
                                    const Text(
                                      'Reminder Before:',
                                      style: kSubHeading2TextStyle,
                                    ),

//hour before (reminder)
                                    const Text(
                                      'Hour',
                                      style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                    ),

                                    GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                      builder: (hourController) {
                                        return Slider(
                                          label: 'Hour',
                                          divisions: 23,
                                          activeColor: kPrimaryColor,
                                          value: calendarController.hourValue,
                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                            //TODO: implement slider on dialog in reminder page
                                            hourController.changeHour(val);
                                          },
                                        );
                                      }
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                          builder: (hourController) {
                                            return IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                hourController.increaseOneHour();
                                              },
                                              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                                            );
                                          }
                                        ),
                                        GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                          builder: (hourController) {
                                            return Text(
                                              '${(hourController.hourValue * 23).toInt().toString()} hours',
                                              style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                            );
                                          }
                                        ),
                                        GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                          builder: (hourController) {
                                            return IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                hourController.decreaseOneHour();
                                              },
                                              icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                                            );
                                          }
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
//                                  s
                                    ///minutes before (reminder)
                                    const Text(
                                      'Minute',
                                      style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                    ),

                                    ///MINUTE SLIDER
                                    GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                      builder: (minuteController) {
                                        return Slider(
                                          label: 'Minute',
                                          divisions: 59,
                                          activeColor: kPrimaryColor,
                                          value: calendarController.minuteValue,
                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                            minuteController.changeMin(val);
                                          },
                                        );
                                      }
                                    ),

                                    ///MINUTE + -
                                    GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                      builder: (minuteController) {
                                        return Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                          children: [
                                            IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                minuteController.increaseOneMin();

                                              },
                                              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              '${(minuteController.minuteValue * 59).toInt().toString()} minutes',
                                              style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                            ),
                                            IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                minuteController.decreaseOneMin();
                                              },
                                              icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      }
                                    ),



                                    ///frequency
                                    const Text(
                                      'How many times you wish to be reminded?',
                                      style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                    ),
                                    GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                      builder: (frequencyController) {
                                        return Slider(
                                          label: 'Frequency',
                                          divisions: 10,
                                          activeColor: kPrimaryColor,
                                          value: frequencyController.frequency,
                                          onChanged: (val) {
                                            frequencyController.changeFrequency(val);
                                          },
                                        );
                                      }
                                    ),
//
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    children: [
                                      GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                        builder: (frequencyController) {
                                          return Text(
                                            '${(frequencyController.frequency * 10).toInt().toString()} times',
                                            style:
                                            kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                          );
                                        }
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),

                                  //travel medium
                                    GetBuilder<CalendarController>(
                                      builder: (dropDownController) {
                                        return Text(
                                          dropDownController.dropdownvalue == 'Select Category'
                                              ? 'Flight Name'
                                              : dropDownController.dropdownvalue + ' Name/ Number',
                                          style: kSubHeading2TextStyle,
                                        );
                                      }
                                    ),
                                    TextField(
                                      controller:
                                          travelMediumTxtEditingController,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: 'Type here',
                                        hintStyle: kNormalTextStyle.copyWith(
                                          color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300,
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      height: 8,
                                    ),

                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 4,
                                          child: TextField(
                                            controller:
                                                txtSourceTxtEditingController,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                            maxLines: 1,
                                            style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              labelText: 'Source',
                                              hintText: 'Type source here',
                                              labelStyle: kNormalTextStyle.copyWith(
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300,
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                              ),
                                              hintStyle:
                                                  kNormalTextStyle.copyWith(
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300,
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),


                                        const VerticalDivider(
                                          width: 4,
                                          color: kDarkPrimaryColor,
                                        ),


                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 4,
                                          child: TextField(
                                            controller:
                                                txtDestinationTxtEditingController,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,

                                            maxLines: 1,
                                            style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              labelText: 'Destination',
                                              labelStyle: kNormalTextStyle.copyWith(
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300,
                                                fontSize: 12,

                                              ),
                                              hintText: 'Type destination here',
                                              hintStyle:
                                                  kNormalTextStyle.copyWith(
                                                color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300,
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),

                                    const SizedBox(
                                      height: 8,
                                    ),
//special message
                                    const Text(
                                      'Any special message?',
                                      style: kSubHeading2TextStyle,
                                    ),
                                    TextField(
                                      controller:
                                          specialMessageTxtEditingController,
                                      style: kSubHeading3TextStyle,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          hintStyle: kNormalTextStyle.copyWith(
                                            color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                          ),
                                          hintText:
                                              'Any special message that you may wish to be sent to you, when being reminded? \n(optional)'),
                                    ),

                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                        children: [
                                          GetBuilder<CalendarController>(builder: (calendarController){
                                            return ElevatedButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                if (validateData()) {

                                                  addReminder(hr: (calendarController.hourValue * 23).toInt(), min: (calendarController.minuteValue * 59).toInt(), dropDownValue: calendarController.dropdownvalue, frequency: (calendarController.frequency * 10).toString());
                                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                                }


//TODO: handle submit button action button on popup dialog in reminder page
                                              },
                                              child: const Text('Submit'),
                                            );
                                          })
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black,),
                    ),
```

[dialog before keyboard appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTclI.png)
[screen pixel overflow after the keyboard appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fijv.png)

I tried Expanded widget.
Then I tried with SingleChildScrollView, but the issue is still there.
I want that when the keyboards appears, either the container gets smaller or it should go behind the screen without causing any overflow.